# What percent of users visit meta sites?

Tags: discussion, meta

What metrics are available to understand how many users visit meta sites?

Specifically Stack Overflow; although, it would be interesting to compare rates of meta users on different Stack Exchange sites.

For example, from the [users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) tab at Stack Overflow, it appears there are ~3,141,854 users.

On Meta Stack Overflow [users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) tab there are ~196,525 users.

So, is it fair to say that 6.25% of users visit meta?

Badges could also be used, especially to understand participation - such as [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) where 16,600 users or 0.5% have 1 post with score of 2; or [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) where 1,500 users or 0.05% have 10 posts with score of 2.

Clearly this complicated by the meta split, in which [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) has ~113,554 users (3.6%); or even fewer users across all network sites than Meta Stack Overflow.  Badge totals are also persisted from before the meta split. As well, a user does not need to login to view meta content.

To me, it seems a user needs to visit meta now and again to understand how the site is to be used.

Is 6.25% fair, and does that represent the desired or appropriate participation expected?

Comment: *Visit* Meta or *participate* in Meta? They are likely to be very different. Now that the Community Bulletin exists, advertising enticing-looking questions from Meta, I'll bet a large percentage of our regular users visit Meta on occasion. But it is a very small percentage that participate—either by regular voting, posting questions or answers, or whatever else.

Comment: Since well over 50% of the users on SO have 1 point, it might be better to discount them on the grounds that they wouldn't know what MSO was in the first place.  (Page 33666 of 87278 contains the first uses with 1 point in the all-time rankings.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Not only 1 rep users, but any user with <5 reputation (they can't participate on Meta, even if they wanted to).

Comment: OK; in that case, it is page 30868 of 87284 (so there've been 6 pages worth of new users in 3 hours or so) where the users with 4 points start.  At 36 users per page, that's just over 1.1M users eligible to participate.  If about 200K users are listed, that's close to 20% of eligible users have visited MSO at some time or another.

Comment: I've become a regular visitor of the meta stackoverlfow ever since they put up the "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts" panel on the right. The idea to put it there was a great one.

Comment: @asprin the community bulletin is several years old... just that SO didn't have it activated.

Comment: I think 100% of the people you see here have visited the meta site.

Comment: May I ask what do you need to know the % of users who participate/visit meta? What is this number going to be useful for?

Comment: @mehow As indicated, meta sites help users and vice versa - refining usage as well as a platform to improve the site through discussion of features and bug reporting.  Both ways - understanding meta community base helps to understand survey or polling totals; or understanding resolution of issues on the site.  From the review system, or by user comments, there's substantial links to meta to help guide users in practices of the site.  Perhaps there would be less issues with the site if more people spent time on meta?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Shog9: [294,542 users active (post/vote) on SO during the past 30 days. 6,845 of them active on MSO. So, a hair over 2%](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2036664#2036664)

Note: "30 days" being April 12 to May 11

> Shog9: 4515 10K users active (post/vote) on SO during the past 30 days, 1090 of them active on MSO
>
> hichris123: @Shog9 How much of that is due to the community bulletin?
>
> Shog9:  probably a fair bit
>
> Now, that's all interesting for a couple of reasons...
>
> #1, it's great that a reasonable number of the folks involved on SO are contributing to MSO. Not just distantly aware of it, not just passively reading it, but actively posting or voting on other's posts
>
> #2, that's a lot of people on meta, but it's still nowhere near a majority of users, even high-rep users. Think about that next time you're about to make some sort of statement about meta reflecting the SO community's decision on something: it's a small, biased sample - useful information, but useless as a binding vote.

The conversation starts [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2036657#2036657); note that these stats are couple months old, if anyone wants newer data, poke Shog.

Comment: Pokes @Shog9 - It might be interesting to see whether these numbers have *changed* in the meantime (but not "important" - the question about the (approximate) ratio between active users on both sites is answered)

Comment: @Thursday Thanks, didn't know that. I thought might be interesting in view of the recent complaints about declining quality etc, but as I said: It's not really "important"...

Comment: Meta is not only for contributing but for reading too. I think that's what OP had in mind. Do we have any statistics about the users that simply **read** meta, without posting anything?